# LASSO solution when $p \gg n$

Tags: least-squares, lasso

We know that when $p \gg n$ we don't have a unique least squares solution.
But, in the same scenario, does LASSO have a solution?

LASSO uses the least squares term as part of its cost function (i.e., least squares + the penalty).

Comment: See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1369148600).